# Post "http://localhost:4242/webhook": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4242: connect: connection refuse

Tags: typescript, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe in next.js 13 with ts and app router config.

I used `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:4242/webhook` to create stripe event in my local machine but I getting this error `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:4242/webhook` for every event.

Comment: You said "getting this error" but then copied the listen command again. Are you getting a 404 error? Probably you need to ensure you're pointing at your webhook endpoint running locally, but please share more details about the error you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `localhost:4242/webhook` you should use your next.js port and API route like:

`localhost:3000/app/api/checkout/stripe/webhook`